# Excel: mortgage monthly payment with constant principal payment

Tags: excel

In Excel, the `pmt` function calculates the constant monthly total payment (interest + principal) on a mortgage. The `ppmt` function extracts the (time-varying) principal payment with a constant monthly total payment.

Is there a function to calculate the (time-varying) total monthly payment if the principal payment is fixed over time instead? In this case the total monthly payment is decreasing over time.

Thank you for tips!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If the principle payment is fixed, then the repayment period is fixed, too (principle / payment).  So what do you want this function to tell you?

Answer (score 1):

If i understood fully what you want these formulas do it.

[image]

After creating the table copy down the sheet the following cells as long as need
A7;B7;C6;D6;F6

The H15 cell content = SUM(F:F)

Comment: you have hardcoded the monthly interest rate calculation in cell `B6`. I think it would be slightly easier to see if you calculated the monthly repayment of principal as amount borrowed divided by number of repayments (ie `$D$1/$D$3` so 4166.67 or 4167 depending on your rounding level). There's an issue about monthly interest: you have used simple interest: monthly rate, r, is R/12 where R is annual rate. An alternative is compound interest where (1+r)^12 is 1+R, so r=(1+R)^(1/12) - 1. However, this is really about understanding the lender's approach to this: either might apply.